# NSOperations and iOS architecture questions

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm getting deeper into `NSOperations` stuff and I have question connected to iOS architecture:

*1.Is it possible in iOS system architecture to kill my `NSOperations` / `NSOperationsQueue` that I call?

*2.What can be done to do this? what kind of situation?

*3. What do iOS when is running on low resources and `NSOperationQueue` is allocated and init'ed with new `NSOperations` queued?

*4. As I read about `NSOperations` - they cannot run till get status `isReady=YES` to execute, or can get `isReady=NO`, if there are still unfinished operations on which it is dependent.
What kind of dependent operations can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No, it will not do that, unless it kills your whole applications.
In this case, you will be notified from `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`
 in your app delegqte

2) N/A

3) It will produce a low memory warning notification. See [Low memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW52)

4) Operation queue will process all your NSOperations. NSOperations dependancies are only inducted by you. For "isReady" to be equal to NO, it would require you to change the value manually.

Comment: what are conditions of killing application?